# Can I clear the screen in Python's IDLE Shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, python-idle

I'm trying to clear the screen in Python's IDLE shell, and so far haven't found any working mechanism to do so.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can utilize `os.system`: `import os; _ = os.system("clear")`

Comment: IDLE is for development; it's not meant to be the final user interface for your script.

Comment: Note that "rants in disguise" are off-topic here; so is development history except to the extent that it has practical impact. "Can I clear the screen in the IDLE shell?" is probably on-topic. "Why is there no way to clear the screen in the IDLE shell?" is not.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley, did you actually test that that works? `clear` just writes terminal control codes; if IDLE honors them, it'll honor them just as much if they're printed by `print()` or `sys.stderr.write()` or so forth, so if that does work it suggests that there are lots of other (much more efficient and much less OS-dependent) options available as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An unobvious way to clear Shell is to open an empty file, save it if necessary, close Shell, and run the empty file.  Pretty poor, but it works.  Select-All and Delete works in editors but not Shell.  Issue [50393](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/50393) is about adding an obvious and direct way to clear Shell. But there are several [technical issues](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/50393#issuecomment-1093470448) which I have gotten no feedback on.

I will take your question as a vote for doing something, whatever I think best.